# How to write Python output to file from for loop?

Tags: python, instagram

I am using the Instaloader package to scrape some data from Instagram.

Ideally, I am looking to scrape the posts associated to a specific hashtag. I created the code below, and it outputs lines of scraped data, but I am unable to write this output to a .txt, .csv, or .json file.

I tried to first append the loop output to a list, but the list was empty. My efforts to output to a file have also been unsuccessful.

I know I am missing a step here, please provide any input that you have! Thank you.

```
    import instaloader
    import json

    L= instaloader.Instaloader()
    for posts in L.get_hashtag_posts('NewYorkCity'):
       L.download_hashtag('NewYorkCity', max_count = 10)
       with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(posts, f)
       break

    print('Done')
```

Comment: Watch your indentation, your `json.dump` line will raise a `SyntaxError`. Also, your loop will only do one iteration and will just `break` from the loop after writing to `output.json` once

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems the spacing might be a bit off. When you use the open command with the "with" statement it does a try: / finally: on the file object.

In your case you created a variable f representing this file object. I believe if you make the following change you can write your json data to the file.

```
    import instaloader
    import json

    L= instaloader.Instaloader()
    for posts in L.get_hashtag_posts('NewYorkCity'):
       L.download_hashtag('NewYorkCity', max_count = 10)
       with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
           f.write(json.dump(posts))
           break

    print('Done')
```

I am sure you intended this, but if your goal in the break was to only get the first value in the loop returned you could make this edit as well

```
for posts in L.get_hashtag_posts('NewYorkCity')[0]:
```

This will return the first item in the list.

If you would like the first 3, for example, you could do [:3]

See this tutorial on [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)